# Escape character in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, escaping

For displaying the character **&** in a button as text, i am using **&&**

I would like to display the string **%** in another one button but the **&%** does not work.

So how can i display the char **%**

By using this ***`btn5.Text = "%"`*** the percentage symbol is not displayed at all!

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? Windows Forms? WPF? I've just tried a WinForms app, and % doesn't need any escaping for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If &% doesn't work, try using %% instead. I know DevExpress was first developed in Delphi and in Delphi, the % character is an escape character too!

And a follow-up, based on [this link](http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=xtraeditors/customdocument1498.htm&levelup=true) I found you might have to use \% instead of &%, %% or just %...

If that doesn't work, you can either contact the [Support department of DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/) or check the source code, if you have those available.

Problem is, no one ever considered defining one single escape character.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a devexpress button does something non-standard with its button captions? A standard button should have no problem displaying a % character.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the devx button control source code with Reflector?

Answer (score 0):

Just having % on its own works, there is no need to escape it

Answer (score 0):

I can not confirm your problem. Adding a button (type System.Windows.Forms.Buton) to a form with .Text equal to "%" worked for me both at design and at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Btn5.Text = Chr(37)

Comment: the question says "

By using this btn5.Text = "%" the percentage symbol is not displayed at all!

"

I tested Btn5.Text = Chr(37) and it is displayed just fine.